# Code is Giving unexpected results

Tags: c

I am just experimenting with fork() c++ function.but I found Surprising results

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
int main()
{
 int x=0;
  int i;
  for( i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
    fork();
    x=x+5;
    printf("%d\n",x);
   sleep(2);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This code is giving output as expected
5

5

10

10

10

10

but same code behaves very differently when I replaced new line in printf with space

```
int main()
{
 int x=0;
  int i;
  for( i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
    fork();
    x=x+5;
    printf("%d  ",x);
   sleep(2);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

5      10      5      10      5      10      5      10

Can anyone tell why so abnormal result came when I replaced new line with space.

I am using gcc compiler
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: thanks a lot Sir...got the reason....Sorry I could not find it so posted..I will take care in future

Answer (score 4):

The standard output stream is normally line-buffered.  When you include the `\n` when printing, you flush the stream and the `5` is printed to the console before the next `fork()` is called.  When you don't include it, it's just hanging around in a buffer someplace and gets duplicated along with everything else when `fork` is called.

Answer (score 3):

`printf` is only guaranteed to flush the buffer when you do a `\n` If you don't do one, then other things can be written to a buffer and then flushed later, with the elements in different orders (depending one when it was added to the buffer).